# How select checkbox in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying when I click on a checkbox it should get selected and save its value true in localstorage  so that if the page is refreshed it should get value from the localstorage, similarly for second checkbox if it is selected too then also save its value true in localstorage.

In simple way if I select a both the checkboxes it should retain even after page refresh this is what I am trying for

Here is my code is what I have tried

Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-architecture-p2nrg?file=/src/App.js:0-1760

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  const data = {
    naming: localStorage.getItem("naming") || false,
    fullname: localStorage.getItem("fullname") || false
  };
  const [currentCheckboxId, setCheckboxId] = React.useState(data);

  const setCheckbox = event => {
    const naming = event.target.checked;
    console.log(naming);
    localStorage.setItem("naming", naming);
    setCheckboxId({
      ...data,
      naming: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  const setCheckbox2 = event => {
    const fullname = event.target.checked;
    console.log(fullname);
    localStorage.setItem("fullname", fullname);
    setCheckboxId({
      ...data,
      fullname: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Form>
        <>
          <Form.Check
            onChange={setCheckbox}
            type="checkbox"
            label="Check me out"
            id="first"
            checked={currentCheckboxId.naming}
          />
          <Form.Group controlId="email">
            <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </Form.Group>
        </>
        <>
          <Form.Check
            onChange={setCheckbox2}
            type="checkbox"
            label="Check me out"
            id="second"
            checked={currentCheckboxId.fullname}
          />
          <Form.Group controlId="fullname">
            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
          </Form.Group>
        </>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. **Initialize** the state with `false`
2. Use `useEffect` to run at **mounted** and retrieve checkbox values from **LocalStorage** and setState accordingly
3. Use `setState` with [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to **set new state which depends on current state**

```
export default function App() {

  // 1. Initially "false"
  const [currentCheckboxId, setCheckboxId] = React.useState({
    naming: false,
    fullname: false
  });

  // 2. useEffect to run @ mounted:
  // get from LS and update the state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = {
      naming: localStorage.getItem('naming') === 'true' ? true : false,
      fullname: localStorage.getItem('fullname') === 'true' ? true : false
    };
    setCheckboxId(data);
  }, []);

  const setCheckbox = event => {
    const naming = event.target.checked;
    console.log('naming', naming);
    localStorage.setItem('naming', naming);

    // 3. use "function" with prevData as first argument to setState
    setCheckboxId(prevData => ({
      ...prevData,
      naming: naming
    }));
  };

  const setCheckbox2 = event => {
    const fullname = event.target.checked;
    console.log('fullname', fullname);
    localStorage.setItem('fullname', fullname);

    // 3. same as above
    setCheckboxId(prevData => ({
      ...prevData,
      fullname: fullname
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Form>
        <>
          <Form.Check
            onChange={setCheckbox}
            type="checkbox"
            label="Check me out"
            id="first"
            checked={currentCheckboxId.naming}
          />
          {/* Rest of your code */}
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-haze-d2kq9?file=/src/App.js:138-2118).